# How to download all the source code from a opengork site?

Tags: download

We got a [opengork](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Project+opengrok/) site to host all java source code for our reference.I want to download them to local. How can I achieve that? Don't tell me I can download it manually one by one, because there are thousands of java file.

Comment: there's a "source only" archive *bang* in the middle of the page

Comment: i think he wants to download files off a site he uses at work, not download and install opengork

Comment: @Geek You are right.